# Does gcp load balancer support different port between front end and back end

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Assume the front end port is 443 doing ssl termination 
The backend instance port is port 8080 which is clear text

Anyway to configure that? I can not see that option while it is available in AWS

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can do that. We can configure `TCP load-balancer` with `SSL-Proxy` which is listen on port `443` and also configure `SSL cert` and create `backend service` which can listen on any `random port like 8080`.
For more info please visit: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/tcp-ssl/

Comment: Where would you configure the front end port -> 443 ? I did not see any configuration port on front end? Does it mean using SSL-Proxy, it default to 443? What if I want to use another port. Did not see any configuration on front end port configuration

Comment: You can't specify port other than 443 on SSL-proxy.